# Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, business-process-management

I have created a BPM Project using developer studio and cloned it in BPM Suite 6.3.0 and is working fine. But the response time was about 5 sec(in REST - when i hit the url using rest client). Now i am cloning the same project in version 6.4.0 and when i try to open data models it gives me the error

> Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF.

My test Scenarios are working fine i am getting the desired output.

Comment: Don't you have some forgotten dependency in your project? AFAIK, there is no `com.microsoft.*` dependency in JBoss BPM Suite.

Comment: I have cloned the project from my git repository in BRMS version 6.4, and the same i have cloned in BRMS 6.3. In BRMS 6.3 it's working fine. In my project i am using Apache POI(library) to read Excel. After some research i found that Apache POI requires com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF, but the dependency is resolved in 6.3 and in developer studio but not in 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED -**

in new version in BPM Suite(6.4.0) they restrict the engine to not include classes from the dependent libraries. So to use other libraries I had defined in 'package-names-white-list' file. This is added to define which classes should be verified during rule authoring.Since i am using POI directly so there is no need to verify these classes

Steps -

1. Open the project in the Authoring perspective
2. Switch to the Repository View
3. Open the package-names-white-list file in the root
   folder of the project
4. Add the following content: org.kie.example.**
5. Save the file